# Posting Hindi characters through ASIHTTPS request using NSURL

Tags: ios, unicode, asihttprequest

I am stuck at sending Unicode characters (Hindi) as parameters in URL. It reaches in an unacceptable format on server. It prints correctly in console but when converted to NSURL using method urlWithString:, the string converts to unreadable format.
Notable fact is I was able to read correctly in Hindi,if server sent it directly from change in database.

Edit: (adding code)

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[completeURLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultUserAgentString:@"ipad"];
[request setAllowCompressedResponse:YES];
[request setShouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground:YES];
request.requestMethod = requestType;
[request setTimeOutSeconds:180];
[request setCachePolicy:ASIUseDefaultCachePolicy];
[request addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"text/json; charset=UTF-8"];
//request.responseEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
request.defaultResponseEncoding = NSUTF8StringEncoding;
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
```

[request startSynchronous];

Comment: Have you tried encoding the string before sending it?

Comment: Please check the edit made for code